# add_role() run only once?

Tags: user-roles, actions, capabilities

I was surprised to discover that add_role() modifies the database and fails if the role already exists. There are two implications here, one first more serious than the other: 1) if you're in development and update your add_role code, you must first remove_role() 2) once you have it right, you should never have to run that code again.

So typically I have been putting my add_role() inside a wp_loaded action hook. And since I'm in development, I've also added a remove_role() before my add_role so I can be sure that if I modify my list of caps, it will actually take effect.

But clearly this is now being run every time a page of the blog is being accessed. Okay, I could put it in an admin-only action, or I could create a plugin page maybe under Users or Tools where this role can be created once. I guess I'm hoping there's a simpler, more elegant solution out there.

I don't imagine there's a run_once kind of action is there?

Or is the best practice just to add the role and then use add_cap() a bunch of times? And even then I imagine add_cap is accessing the db.

Just thinking in terms of the best way to reduce unncessary db access. What are your best practices?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this question..Just adding `remove_role()` function before `add_role()` helped me.

Comment: You could just do `if ( ! wp_roles()->is_role( 'my_role' ) ) { add_role() }`

Comment: @Gavin I like that. Obviously this question is super old and maybe things have changed in WP about how roles are handled. I'd want to dive under the hood to see whether `is_role()` does some kind of database check or not. IIRC all the roles are loaded into memory somewhere in the startup sequence, so maybe `is_role()` doesn't need to access the DB for that info, so your solution could be pretty effective in that case!

Comment: @TomAuger You got me curious so I looked up `is_role()` and all that the function contains is `return isset( $this->role_names[ $role ] );` so yeah you're right. There's basically no overhead.

Comment: @Gavin why don't you submit a new answer and we can revise the accepted answer, because your solution (in 2023) is wayyyy more straightforward.

Comment: @TomAuger Sure, good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not have worked when this question was asked, but a much simpler solution is something like this:

```
if ( ! wp_roles()->is_role( 'my_role' ) ) {
    add_role( 'my_role', 'My Role', $capabilities );
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The user roles and capabilities are saved in the database so once you have you have used `add_role()` its saved and then next load WordPress will know that role just like the built in roles.

Now if you look at the function `add_role()` more specifically [at line 141](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L141) you will see that it only saves the role and capabilities in the database if the var `$use_db` is set to true (which he is by default) so you can simply change it before you call your `add_role()` function and the role won't be saved.

try:

```
//globalize $wp_roles
global $wp_roles;
//set use_db to flase
$wp_roles->use_db = false;
//then add your role
$wp_roles->add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities );
```

Update:

If its in a test/development environment then i see no downside, but if you are on a live environment then you save the time it take to create that on role every load.

As for best practice run once, if in a plugin you should use `register_activation_hook` and for any thing else i use a simple custom made conditional function:

```
function run_once($key){
    $test_case = get_option('run_once');
    if (isset($test_case[$key]) && $test_case[$key]){
        return false;
    }else{
        $test_case[$key] = true;
        update_option('run_once',$test_case);
        return true;
    }
}

**usage:**
if (run_once('add_user_role')){
    //do you stuff and it will only run once
}
```

Comment: Aw crap. I even knew about that too from some earlier rooting about the WP_Roles class. Can you think of any downside to NOT using the database for roles? And is there a WP best practice for doing something only once?

Comment: Thanks for the update - I like the simplicity of the update_option solution

Comment: Not really satisfying but it seems to be the best solution 

Comment: This function `run_once` increasing too much read/write database operations on each page load. Please don't use this.