# How to run a function once on every post in database?

Tags: functions, save-post

I have a simple function that automatically formats the whole post after publishing/updating.

It's hooked on:

```
add_action('save_post', 'myFunction');
```

I would like to format every post, that I already have in database. I know I can open every post and click on update to call the "save_post" hook on myFunction on the post, but my post database is pretty big..

Is it possible to **run the function just once on every already published post** somehow or update every post so the function will be called by the hook automatically?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible. Something like this should affect all posts that are currently published. Literally run this once and then disable it by commenting out the add_action or you will have a bunch of unwanted queries to the database.

Running once: With this code placed in your functions.php, the function will run when the front end of your site is loaded in a browser. Load the home page of your site in a browser then disable the function. Confirm that your post format was applied to existing posts.

```
     add_action( 'init', 'my_function', 10);

     function my_function() {
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish');
        $pages = get_pages($args);
        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            // Do something here. Call your formatting function
            }
    }
```

Edit: If it absolutely must run not more than once, have your function look for an SQL table with a boolean value of true or false. If false or table does not exist, run the function, create the table and set it to true.

Comment: It's better to make a plugin and register the activation hook (`register_activation_hook`), so it'll run only on plugin activation. And [here's](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/25667/12615) a function to run only once without using the plugin or theme activation technique.

Comment: I agree that's a good way to ensure it runs once.

Answer (score 0):

Might also consider backing up database and trying an SQL find and replace. Depends on what you are trying to do to all of your posts:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'Find This String', 'Replace With This String');
```